# How do I find $\min_{z,z'~s.t. \|z\|=\|z'\|=1} \|A^Tz-B^Tz'\|$ where $A$ and $B$ have length 1 columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming, svd

For

- $n\times m$ matrices $A$ and $B$ ($n>>m$), which also have length 1 columns
- $rank(A)=rank(B)=m$
- $n$-dimensional vector $z$
- The $l2$ norm for vectors and Frobenius norm for matrices

I need to find
$$\min_{z,z'~s.t. \|z\|=\|z'\|=1} \|A^Tz-B^Tz'\|$$

Do you think there is a closed solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are minimizing over $z$ and $z'$, but your expression does not involve variables named $z$ or $z'$, and is therefore constant with respect to them. The minimum is therefore $\|A^Tx - B^Ty\|$. Presumably this isn't what you intended, but if you want any help, you'll need to fix the post to show what you actually did intend.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes typo! Good catch, thank you!

Comment: What spaces are we talking about here? Are $z,z'$ vectors or matrices? What do you mean by "length 1 columns"? That $A, B$ have only one row? What norm is "$\|\phantom x\|_F$"?

Comment: Assuming my guesses as to your meanings are correct, I *think* the minimum will be  $|\|A\| - \|B\||$, but I haven't validated it. If $A, B$ are both not invertible, it will definitely be $0$.